# How do I optimize this logic?

Tags: java, c++, algorithm

I have following scenario:-

```
if( condition1 == true )
{
/*
a code block or fuction call
*/
}
else
{
 if( condition2 == true )
 {
 /*
 same code block or function call
 */
 }
}
```

Here, a particular block of code has to be executed if a condition1 is true.
Else if condition1 is false but if condition2 is true, then also same block of code has to be executed.
How can I write this logic in an efficient way so as to not write same block twice, or call same fuction twice.

Comment: if the same code block is called in both cases, why use an if?

Comment: @OlimpiuPOP Because if both conditions are false, the code won't be executed.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With a simple logical `OR` (very basic stuff for any language).

```
if(condition1 || condition2) {
    // Code
}
```

Using `==` (or `!=`) is often discouraged, since adds verbosity needlessly. Writing `condition1` is the same as `condition1 == true` and testing for false can be made with `!condition1` (the logical `NOT` operator).

Comment: +1. Side note: In the question, you can see `if(condition1 == true)`: I would explain why the `==true` part can be omitted, it might not be that easy to understand for the OP

Answer (score 0):

If your function call return something int, char etc.
You can use this :-

```
condition1?function():(condition2?function():1);
```

It says, if condition1 is true execute function, else if condition2 is true execute function else nothing.
Hope it is clear.